# Apostrophes at the beginning of stanzas in Byron's "The Giaour"

Tags: poetry, lord-byron, orthography, the-giaour

My question is about Byron's [*The Giaour*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Giaour) and the **opening apostrophe** at the beginning of a stanza. For example:

> 'His floating robe around him folding,
> Slow sweeps he through the columned aisle;
> With dread beheld, with gloom beholding
> The rites that sanctify the pile
> But when the anthem shakes the choir,
> And kneel the monks, his steps retire;
> By yonder lone and wavering torch
> His aspect glares within the porch;
> There will he pause till all is done -
> And hear the prayer, but utter none
> ...

Why do some stanzas begin with an apostrophe, whereas others don't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an apostrophe but an opening quotation mark, paired with a closing quotation mark at the end of the stanza. If I am understanding rightly, this stanza is spoken by a monk into whose monastery the Giaour has come, and he is describing the Giaour's behaviour. (Hence e.g. his invocation of St Francis later in the stanza.)

In at least [one early edition](https://archive.org/details/giaourfragmentof13byro/page/44/mode/2up) the typographical convention is different and more explicit, with every single line of the stanza preceded by a quotation mark.

(This isn't something you asked about but may also be worth mentioning: Some lines in this poem do in fact begin with apostrophes -- there are several beginning "'Tis". This is just an abbreviated version of "It is".)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Gareth! The topic of narrator in The Giaour is very interesting.